# LINQ let repeat data

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem with a LINQ simple example. I don't receive the expected result. This is the code:

```
        string[] postres = { "pay de manzana", "pastel de chocolate", "manzana caramelizada", "fresas con crema", "pay de manzana y pera" };

        IEnumerable<string> mispays = from p in postres
                                      let manzanitas = (
                                        from p1 in postres
                                        where p1.Contains("manzana")
                                        orderby p1
                                        select p1)
                                      from p2 in manzanitas
                                      where p2.Contains("pay")
                                      select p2;

        foreach (string postre in mispays)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(postre);
        }
```

I expect this result:

pay de manzana
pay de manzana y pera

But I receive this:

pay de manzana
pay de manzana y pera
pay de manzana
pay de manzana y pera
pay de manzana
pay de manzana y pera
pay de manzana
pay de manzana y pera
pay de manzana
pay de manzana y pera

So the code repeate 5 times my expected result.
¿Could you tell me why? and ¿How can I receive the expected result?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why the first line `from p in postres` since you don't seem to use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another version.

```
string[] postres = { "pay de manzana", "pastel de chocolate", "manzana caramelizada", "fresas con crema", "pay de manzana y pera" };

var keyWords = new string[] {"manzana", "pay"};

var found = postres
    .Where( p => keyWords.All( w => p.Contains(w)))
    .ToList();

foreach (var o in found) Console.WriteLine(o);
```

```
pay de manzana
pay de manzana y pera
```

---

Update for the following comment.

> Do you know any way to do it using "let"?

```
var found =
    from p in postres
    let keyWords = new string[] {"manzana", "pay"}
    let sentence = p.ToLower()
    where keyWords.All( w => sentence.Contains(w.ToLower()))
    select p;
    // ToLower()s are obviously optional, but it gives you an extra let ;)
```

Comment: Nice, didn't think of that way. This is probably more scalable if number of words to search grow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
Do you know any way to do it using "let"?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be going through `postres` too many times, leading to 5 times the expected result. This is probably due to the `from p in postres` at the beginning, which is unused and causes the rest of your query to run 5 times(length of `postres`) more than expected. You only need to go through `postres` once.

I would simplify your query to:

```
IEnumerable<string> mispays = from p in postres
                              where p.Contains("manzana") && p.Contains("pay")
                              select p;

Console.WriteLine("{ " + string.Join(", ", mispays) + " }");
// { pay de manzana, pay de manzana y pera }
```

You can also try the other LINQ syntax:

```
var result = postres.Where(s => s.Contains("manzana") && s.Contains("pay"));

 Console.WriteLine("{ " + string.Join(", ", result) + " }");
// { pay de manzana, pay de manzana y pera }
```

**Explanation:**

- First use [`Enumerable.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) or [`where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-clause) clause to filter out your array `postres`
- Then specify the inner predicate to only include strings than contain `"manzana"` and `"pay"` using [`String.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
Do you know any way to do it using "let"?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is because of the first line in your query :

```
from p in postres
```

this means to iterate through the whole loop, therefore your five results. You don't have much to change :

```
IEnumerable<string> mispays = from p2 in (
                                        from p1 in postres
                                        where p1.Contains("manzana")
                                        orderby p1
                                        select p1)
                              where p2.Contains("pay")
                              select p2;
```

Query syntax can be very tricky. The method syntax is usually easier to understand, as shown in the other answers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
Do you know any way to do it using "let"?